# How to give static local IP address to RADIUS Server software and IIS Server Website?

Tags: iis, windows-server-2012-r2, ip, radius, static-ip

I have following network topology:
[image: Network Topology]

Whenever I turn on my Server all the local IP addresses (in the form 10.0.0.X) of RADIUS Server and IIS Server changes or sometimes port is assigned to SVCHost process of Windows. I am a beginner in networking field. Somehow I was able to make this technology work but only problem is changing IP addresses. I have to visit to the client each day for configuring the IPs.

Please tell me how to assign fix/static IPs to these two server software?

Answer (score 0):

You can exclude 2 IP addresses of the DHCP Server and configure yours servers with them.

Answer (score 0):

Am I understanding correctely: Your Server IPs are dynamically changing on each reboot?

If so, you could enter a reservation inside your DHCP-Server for the MAC-Address of your Server - please note that is always better to assign a static IP-Address (especially when the DHCP-Server is running on the same device, as the DHCP-Role is started a way after the networking).

**To manually change / set an specific IP-Address to IIS-Service:**
Open the IIS-Manager and navigate to the site you want to bind a different IP-Address to and do a right click. Now choose "Bindings". You can now either edit the existing entry and change the IP or add a new entry.

Please note that you have to add a second IP-Adress to your network adapter (in case you don't have more than one network adapter connect with an IP)

**RAS**: As far as I know you cannot change IP Bindings on Routing and RAS - if you have more than one network adapter you can choose the used adapter instead (which would "change" the IP used).

Hope that helps at least a bit.